# mypy causing issue for VSCode integrated testing

Tags: vscode-extensions, mypy

[image: integrated tests getting screwed up]

So we love the VSCode integrated test tool, and we are sort of fans of mypy, but they won't play well together.  When we add the mypy flag to our pytest.ini like so

```
[pytest]
pythonpath=./src
addopts = -vvv --cov --cov-report=term-missing --cov-fail-under=100 --ignore=.vscode --mypy 
filterwarnings =
    ignore:.*pkg_resources.*:DeprecationWarning
```

We lose the integrated test view - it works fine if we just remove the `--mypy` but if it's present we just see a single `setup.py` test as shown in the image.

Looking in the Extension Host output we do see an "Illegal argument: line must be non-negative" error, but not sure how to proceed ...

```
2023-12-21 17:15:52.561 [error] Error: Illegal argument: line must be non-negative
    at m (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:10:1101)
    at new f (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:137:4467)
    at forEach (/Users/samjoseph/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.1/src/client/testing/testController/common/utils.ts:159:50)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at populateTestTree (/Users/samjoseph/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.1/src/client/testing/testController/common/utils.ts:154:27)
    at forEach (/Users/samjoseph/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.1/src/client/testing/testController/common/utils.ts:176:17)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at populateTestTree (/Users/samjoseph/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.1/src/client/testing/testController/common/utils.ts:154:27)
    at forEach (/Users/samjoseph/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.1/src/client/testing/testController/common/utils.ts:176:17)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at populateTestTree (/Users/samjoseph/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.1/src/client/testing/testController/common/utils.ts:154:27)
    at t.PythonResultResolver._resolveDiscovery (/Users/samjoseph/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.1/src/client/testing/testController/common/resultResolver.ts:60:25)
    at t.PythonResultResolver.resolveDiscovery (/Users/samjoseph/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.1/src/client/testing/testController/common/resultResolver.ts:35:21)
    at f.value (/Users/samjoseph/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.1/src/client/testing/testController/pytest/pytestDiscoveryAdapter.ts:22:80)
    at n.y (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:80:1902)
    at n.fire (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:80:2119)
    at t.PythonTestServer._fireDataReceived (/Users/samjoseph/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.1/src/client/testing/testController/common/server.ts:83:43)
    at t.PythonTestServer._resolveData (/Users/samjoseph/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.1/src/client/testing/testController/common/server.ts:65:22)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/samjoseph/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.1/src/client/testing/testController/common/server.ts:28:54)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

Any help or ideas very much appreciated :-)